# How to add slide navigation in ios in nib file

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uinavigationcontroller

I am facing problem to add the slide navigation in nib file.
Please help me

I have an example but its for story board and I want it to use in nib so I can open a menu form left side

```
[SlideNavigationController sharedInstance].rightMenu = rightMenu;
[SlideNavigationController sharedInstance].menuRevealAnimationDuration = .18;


// Creating a custom bar button for right menu
UIButton *button  = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)];
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"gear"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button addTarget:[SlideNavigationController sharedInstance] action:@selector(toggleRightMenu) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem *rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
[SlideNavigationController sharedInstance].rightBarButtonItem = rightBarButtonItem;

    SlideNavigationController *nav = [[SlideNavigationController alloc]  initWithRootViewController:viewCon];
    nav.navigationBarHidden=YES;
    self.window.rootViewController=nav;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this is very neat solution for nib and I'm using it for my own project. You may check it out:
https://maniacdev.com/2013/08/open-source-component-for-making-a-nice-ios-7-control-center-style-animated-side-bar-menu

Answer (score 0):

Create your `LeftMenuViewController` Xib and implementation and header file. In the end you should have these filed:

```
LeftMenuViewController.h
LeftMenuViewController.m
LeftMenuViewController..xib
```

and replace the line

```
LeftMenuViewController *leftMenu = (LeftMenuViewController*)[mainStoryboard
                                                instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"LeftMenuViewController"];
```

with this - to load the controller from a xib

```
LeftMenuViewController *sm = [[A1SideMenuViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"LeftMenuViewController" bundle:nil];
```

Comment: You should create a new question if you change your question completely. My answer regards you question about the Storyboard